# 3rd party code closes, 2016 part 2

Tags: discussion

This question caught my eye in the review queue:

[Adding Instafeed on Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/117833/instafeed-on-magnto-2)

OP is asking how to take code, which is already written, and add it to a page in Magento 2. 4 close votes queue up saying that the topic of the code, An Instafeed script block, is off topic for this site.

I realize that the inner workings of Instafeed would not be supported - but this is someone who has a working block of code who just wants to **add it the correct way** to a site in Magento 2.

We don't need to rehash again, for the 20th time, what is on-topic and what is off-topic for MagentoSE, but this seems **clearly on-topic** to me as the entire point of Magento is to add customizations to it. If this instead said MyCustomClass instead of Instafeed this likely wouldn't have been marked as closed.

Let's be vigilant to try to be helpful and welcoming to newcomers to both this SE site and to Magento 2 by suggesting best practice and pointing newbies to worthwhile resources. One way we can do this is to make a concerted effort during **MageStackDay #5 on June 17 and 18 2016**  to **answer questions**, even the difficult ones, rather than resort to closing out old ones.

Register today at http://magestackday.com/

(And an answer would be welcome on that question)

Comment: your words : `try to be helpful and welcoming to newcomers` what a wonderfull words, I loved it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was one of the close voters and actually hesitated if this was a third party problem or not. But "How to write correct JS" sounds to me like it is **not** a working block of code but there is a problem with the script.

Maybe it's just a language barrier, but IMHO at best the question is unclear and should be improved.

To be clear:

> but this is someone who has a working block of code who just wants to add it the correct way to a site in Magento 2.

With these assumptions, I agree: It's not a close reason.

Answer (score 2):

Yep I was one of the close voter too.

That question is way too broad to be on topic:

- where do you want to add the code ?
- where do the `InstaFeed` JS class come from ?
- how do we retrieve the `YOUR_CLIENT_ID` ?

I actually should have clicked too broad instead of auto clicking Sander's reason but to me it's far from on topic.

Comment: Side note: if you *had* chosen too broad, Stack would have used whichever reason was most popular anyway, and your name would still show up under that reason

Comment: @RobbieAverill oh I didn't know that thanks for the info

Comment: I would have asked for clarification or made an assumption. You're asking a lot of a newcomer who doesn't have even 2k rep anywhere else on SE to get the 101 points join bonus. Pile-on close votes are what drive people away from becoming more active here and get us into the 70% answer rate. We need to instill confidence.

Comment: you are right. it is impossible to answer it. where is that class? with only what he provides there is no way to answer that question or help future users. @philwinkle closing questions helps us get into the 70% answer rate because they will be eventually deleted ;) bad questions are unlikely to be answered anyway.

Comment: This is exactly the issue I'm trying to combat - we shouldn't be working to hit a metric by closing. We should be working to hit it by answering. 2 answers, even if unaccepted, also counts as an answer in the ratio.